# Is my monero safe?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

I sent Monero to an address which was shown in my GUI Wallet, but I think I haven't finished setting up the wallet... should the address start with 4 or 8? Also, is it safe if I don't yet see my total balance?

I see "Daemon failed to start" and also "network status disconnected."

I tried to find something on youtube, reddit, and here, but is too complicated for me and also I'm little scared I may have done something wrong...

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? And are you running active AV (AntiVirus) software?

Answer (score 0):

Your Monero is probably safe.  There are only a few reasons your Monero would not be safe or would not show up in your wallet.

1. After creating your wallet, getting the address, and sending to the address, you decided to create a new wallet.  In this case, the Monero was sent to the original wallet, meaning the current wallet will not detect it.  Check the seed.  If the seed is the same as the original wallet you set up, then you're in that wallet. This may be unlikely, but it's also easy to overlook for a newcomer.
2. Your computer was compromised.  If there is a key logger on your computer, or if someone remotely is able to access your computer, then you are likely to get funds stolen from.  Luckily, this is something you can verify by viewing the wallet's transaction history.  If you see the Monero was spent but you didn't spend it, then you know your computer was compromised and it was stolen. This is unlikely but possible.
3. Your wallet is not synced and up to date.  This is a common issue.  The wallet may not be synced because you are running your own node and it is waiting for the node/daemon to complete syncing with the network. Or you have unsuccessfully connected to a remote node, so the wallet didn't finish syncing.  Either way, your funds would be safe, and the only issue is that your wallet isn't yet aware that Monero was sent to it.

Addresses can either start with a 4 or an 8, depending on whether it's a main address or a subaddress.  Don't worry about that right now, though it would be wise to look into the difference.

Comment: Hey @scoobybejesus would you mind editing the question? I tried deciphering but am struggling. Seems you gleaned enough at least for an answer, so maybe you can edit the Q too?

Comment: @jtgrassie, I've done it.  No problem.